# how to list jars in the dsx spark environment and the jars loaded into the spark JVM?

Tags: ibm-cloud, data-science-experience

I'm hitting issues trying to use spark packages, for example:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource
```

I have listed the files in the lib dir:

```
!find ~/data/libs/
```

I can see my jars are installed:

```
/gpfs/fs01/user/xxxx/data/libs/
/gpfs/fs01/user/xxxx/data/libs/scala-2.11
/gpfs/fs01/user/xxxx/data/libs/scala-2.11/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar
/gpfs/fs01/user/xxxx/data/libs/scala-2.11/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
/gpfs/fs01/user/xxxx/data/libs/pixiedust.jar
/gpfs/fs01/user/xxxx/data/libs/spark-csv_2.11-1.3.0.jar
```

However, the error suggests that spark is unable to see the jar.

How can I list the jars available to spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a scala notebook and ran the following code:

```
def urlses(cl: ClassLoader): Array[java.net.URL] = cl match {
  case null => Array()
  case u: java.net.URLClassLoader => u.getURLs() ++ urlses(cl.getParent)
  case _ => urlses(cl.getParent)
}

val  urls = urlses(getClass.getClassLoader)
println(urls.filterNot(_.toString.contains("ivy")).mkString("\n"))
```

*Attribution: https://gist.github.com/jessitron/8376139*

Running this highlighted an issue with the jvm loading the mongodb driver:

```
error: error while loading <root>, Error accessing /gpfs/fs01/user/xxxx/data/libs/scala-2.11/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
```

This made me realise that although the jar file was present in the correct location was not getting loaded correctly into the jvm.

Answer (score 2):

The classpath is in the environment variable SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH. The following
snippet for execution in a Python notebook yields some duplicates and non-JARs, but also the JARs on the classpath.

```
!ls $(printenv SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH | sed -e 's/:/ /g')
```

Note that the classpath depends on the selected Spark version.